# Linear regression with unusual error terms

Tags: regression, intercept

Suppose that $Y = a + b K + X$ with $0 < X$ and $0 < K$ where $X, Y$ and $K$ are random variables. What are then the expectations of the intercept and slope in the case of a linear regression of $Y$ on $K$?

Comment: it depends on the correlation between $X$ and $K$.

Comment: You need to correct your question to indicate that you are interested in the expectations of the **estimated** intercept and slope.  As it stands, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: In conducting linear regression one generally is concerned about the *conditional* responses and therefore the expectations *conditional* on $K.$  Those can be computed quite generally, but the full expectations--accounting for the distribution of $K$--cannot be generally computed: there's no nice formula for them.  Which are you asking for?

Comment: To AdamO X and K are independent.

Comment: To Isabella Ghement I am interested in the expectations of the estimated intercept and slope.

Comment: To  whuber I am interested in the expectations conditional on K.

Comment: From simulations I get the impression that the expectation of the estimated interception is equal to a + E (X) and the expectation of the  estimated slope equal to b.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure we share a common understanding of the question, I suppose you mean you have independent data $(X_i, K_i, y_i)$ where $(K_i,X_i)$ are $n$ *independent and identically distributed* random variables (you indicate they are positive, but this does not matter), the individual $(K_i, X_i)$ are independent (as you state in a comment), and you use ordinary least squares to estimate $a$ and $b$ in the model

$$y_i = a + b K_i + X_i.$$

Now, *because you assumed $X \gt 0,$* necessarily $E[X_i] \gt 0$ (assuming these expectations are finite).  **This is where your question differs from the usual regression setting.**  The $X_i$ play the role of the "errors" in the model, but because they do not have a zero expectation, *their expectation must be added to the constant $a.$*

One way to see this is to write $$\varepsilon_i = X_i - E[X_i] = X_i - \mu$$  (where $\mu=E[X_i]$ is the common expectation).  These random variables are now legitimate errors because they have zero expectations.  Writing  for the common expectation, your model is the same as

$$y_i = a + b K_i + (\mu + \varepsilon_i) = (a + \mu) + b K_i + \varepsilon_i.$$

Thus, as always in least squares regression,

> the expectation of the slope estimate is $b$ and the expectation of the intercept estimate is the *true intercept,* here seen equal to $a + \mu.$

Unless you know $\mu,$ you cannot determine $a$ from this model: you can only estimate the sum $a+\mu.$  (It sounds like your simulations used zero-mean variables $X_i,$ contrary to the assumptions stated in the question.  Indeed, the expectation of the estimate of $a$ equals $a$ if and only if $\mu=0.$)